# JSONObject and JDBC return format json incorrect

Tags: java, json, database, jdbc

I have facing a problem in my small project. I have spend time about 4 days and not yet have best solution.

This is my source code:

```
public static JSONObject fetchPersonCarInfo() throws Exception {

    // get data from 2 tables: Cars and Manufacturer            
    String query = "SELECT * from mytable";       
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);         
        rs = statement.executeQuery();
        JSONArray carsArray = null;                         
        while(rs.next()) {

            carObj.put("id", (new  string(rs.getString("id"))));                    


            carsArray.put(carObj);

            for(int i=0 ; i< carsArray.length() ; i++) {

            manufacturerObj.put(new String(rs.getString("manufacturer_id")), carsArray);
            manufacturerObj.put(new String(rs.getString("manufacturer_name")), carsArray);
            }
            System.out.println(manufacturerObj.toString());
    }
            System.out.println("Ok");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.close();
        }
            throw e;
    } 
    finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
        }
    }

    return manufacturerObj; 
}
```

And then I build my code and deploy by url, it seem incorrect and there are what's wrong as I expected, and this is my result json format:

```
{
    "1":
    [
        {
            "manufacturer_id": "1",
            "manufacturer_name": "Honda"
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "name": "Honda1",
            "price": "66000"
        }
    ],        
}
```

How I have to change my code to build correct as above json format. thank so much...

Comment: Your first code sample is not JSON

Comment: I would recommend something like `{ "manufacturers": [{"id": 1, "name": "Honda", "cars": [...]}, {"id": 2, "name": "Toyota", "cars": [...]} ] }`

Comment: Dear cricket_007, Yes my first code is not Json, it only Json format for me reference to output. I think my second code have some wrongs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `carObj` section is good, so I would recommend to make it a method.

```
public static JSONObject getCarJSON(String id, String name, String price) {
    JSONObject carObj = new JSONObject();                   
    carObj.put("id", id);                    
    carObj.put("name", name);
    carObj.put("price", price);
    return carObj;
}
```

Your problem seems to be here. You are adding a `personCarObj` to the `carsArray`. That should probably *just* contain cars.

```
JSONObject personCarObj = new JSONObject();                         
personCarObj.put("manufacturer_id", (new String(rs.getString("manufacturer_id"))));
personCarObj.put("manufacturer_name", (new String(rs.getString("manufacturer_name"))));
carsArray.put(personCarObj);
```

And here. For every "car" in the `carsArray`, you are putting a key-value pair into `manufacturerObj` where the value is always the same `carsArray`. `manufacturerObj` should probably *just* contain manufacturer information.

```
for(int i=0 ; i< carsArray.length() ; i++) {

    manufacturerObj.put(new String(rs.getString("manufacturer_id")), carsArray);
    manufacturerObj.put(new String(rs.getString("manufacturer_name")), carsArray);
}
```

---

So, with those recommendations, you want to try to get something like your initially displayed non-JSON.

```
{
    "manufacturers": [{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Honda",
        "cars": [{
            "id": "4",
            "name": "Honda1",
            "price": "66000"
        }]
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Toyota",
        "cars": [{
            "id": "551",
            "name": "Toyota51",
            "price": "3233333"
        }]
    }]
}
```

And the code below might get close (*warning*: not tested). The reason for the map is to capture when you've seen a manufacturer already, then append the data rather than duplicate.

```
JSONArray manufacturerArray = new JSONArray();
HashMap<String, JSONArray> manufacturerMap = new HashMap<String, JSONArray>();

while(rs.next()) {
    String mId = rs.getString("manufacturer_id");
    JSONArray carsArray = manufacturerMap.get(mId);
    if (carsArray == null) {
        carsArray = new JSONArray();
        manufacturerMap.put(mId, carsArray);
    }
    JSONObject manufacturer = new JSONObject();                         
    manufacturer.put("id", mId);
    manufacturer.put("name", rs.getString("manufacturer_name"));                  

    String carId = rs.getString("id");                    
    String carName = rs.getString("name");
    String carPrice = rs.getString("price");
    carsArray.put(getCarJSON(carId, carName, carPrice));

    manufacturer.put("cars", carsArray);
    manufacturerArray.put(manufacturer);
}
JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
result.put("manufacturers", manufacturerArray);
```

---

You *could* use Jackson/Gson to make some POJO's like this

```
class Manufacturer {
    String id, name;
    List<Car> cars;
} 

class Car {
    String id, name, price;
}
```

Then you would serialize a `List<Manufacturer>`

Comment: Maybe it's best solution for me. Thank for your support

Comment: You could also parse out the id and price to int/double if you needed

Comment: Yes, maybe I will type of price is double, ex: 1,500,000 vnd (Vietnam currency).